# Bitmap gets upside down and from right to left after I send the array of pixels from c++ to java through jni with memcpy

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I am memcpying pixel data from the c++ buffer to the java one.
I am using `RGBA` encoding on the c++ part and creating the `bitmap` in `Android` with `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888.`
Then the bitmap gets upside down and from right to left.
rotating the `bitmap` is not an option since it's an expensive operation.
Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you verify that the pixels are left-right, top-bottom? How are you displaying the bitmap? We need more code to help.

Comment: ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(m_data);
bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, null, dstRect, null); and form c++                         std::memcpy(info, pixels, imageSize); where info is the java buffer and pixels is the actual pointer to the bitmap info

Comment: Okay. Bisect the problem: Create a Bitmap from java and put a single pixel in the top-left corner. Draw it like you draw the Bitmap from C++. Is it also flipped in both directions?

Comment: I saved the bmp from c++ to disk and it is normal.

Comment: Can you please be less vague? How exactly did you create that file? The Microsoft bitmap format is bottom-up by default (unless you set a negative height), while Android is top-down. And what about the experiment I proposed?

Comment: You were right, I was saving the bitmap in a microsoft format. How do I switch it to android format? I am getting the bitmap as an array of unsigned chars

Comment: If you cannot change the order in which your source provides the bytes, you either have to reverse your image line by line OR just have Android mirror it at draw time.